# Why this error comes "The plug-in execution failed because no Sandbox Worker processes are currently available"?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, c#-5.0

I am using  an free  trial version of online ms crm 2015 just to understand it and 
I wrote this plugin with threads int them

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;                // for Iplugin interface
using nonitcompany;                     // for earlybinding generated by crmsvcuti.exe
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk;                //for stestate requests
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;       //for stestate requests





namespace Plugin_on_create_deact_rec
{
    public class account_deactivate:IPlugin
    {
        public static int semaphore0 = 0, semaphore1 = 0, semaphore2 = 0;
        public static IPluginExecutionContext context;
        public static IOrganizationServiceFactory factory;
        public static IOrganizationService service;
        public static IServiceProvider serviceProvider_;
        public static Entity accounts;
        public static SetStateRequest deactivate;
        public static SetStateResponse setstate_response;
       public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            serviceProvider_ = serviceProvider;
            ThreadStart _context = new ThreadStart(context_);
            ThreadStart _factory = new ThreadStart(factory_);
            ThreadStart _execute = new ThreadStart(execute_);
            Thread context_t = new Thread(_context);
            Thread factory_t = new Thread(_factory);
            Thread execute_t= new Thread(_execute);
            context_t.Start();
            factory_t.Start();
            execute_t.Start();
            wait(semaphore0);

        }

       private static void context_()
       {
           context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider_.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
           accounts = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
           EntityReference accounts_reference = new EntityReference();
           accounts_reference.LogicalName = accounts.LogicalName;
           accounts_reference.Id = accounts.Id;
           deactivate = new SetStateRequest();
           deactivate.EntityMoniker = accounts_reference;
           deactivate.State = new OptionSetValue((int)AccountState.Inactive);
           deactivate.Status = new OptionSetValue(2);
           signal(semaphore1);
       }
       private static void factory_()
       {
           factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider_.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
           service = (IOrganizationService)factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
           signal(semaphore2);
       }
       private static void execute_()
       {
           wait(semaphore1);
           wait(semaphore2);

               setstate_response = (SetStateResponse)service.Execute(deactivate);
               signal(semaphore0);



       }

       private static void wait(int semaphore)
       {
           while (semaphore == 0)
           {
               //do nothing
           }
           semaphore = semaphore - 1;
       }
       private static void signal(int semaphore)
       {
           semaphore = semaphore + 1;
       }
    }
}
```

i registerd it on create post syncronous mode in accounts entity .

this error come from then after for every sync plugins registered :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: The plug-in execution failed because no Sandbox Worker processes are currently available. Please try again.
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #5CD64A38Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147204723</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>The plug-in execution failed because no Sandbox Worker processes are currently available. Please try again.
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #5CD64A38</Message>
  <Timestamp>2015-03-12T13:19:42.5150181Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[PluginProfiler.Plugins: PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerPlugin]
[dc99cb02-b6c8-e411-80eb-c4346bada6b4: Plugin_on_create_deact_rec.account_deactivate: Create of account (Profiler)]


</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

can any one tell me what the hell happened to my instance of crm ..

Comment: Did you tried to disable the thread operations and work with a single thread?

Comment: yes i did but didn't work for any plugins registered in sync mode ..!